Fetching From Prepopulated Supabase Table Returns Empty Array
This is my first time using supabase realtime, I want to access values in my table in real time and also update them with interactrions from the app. I prepopulated the database in supabase but when I tried to retrieve the data it was empty.

I have attached a picture with the current database setup.
class _TrackerState extends State<Tracker> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final SupabaseClient supabase = Supabase.instance.client;
    final stream = supabase.from('Counter').stream(primaryKey: ["name"]);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: ...
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: stream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
              case ConnectionState.active:
                if (snapshot.hasError) log(snapshot.error.toString());
                log(snapshot.data.toString());

                final data = snapshot.data as List<dynamic>;

                return ...
              default:
                return const Scaffold(
                    body: Center(
                  child: SizedBox(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  ),
                ));
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

console output: [log] []

Try to initialise stream at init method.

The issue is likely due to not having RLS policies set on the table. You can follow this guide to set RLS policies for your table.
https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/postgres/row-level-security
